# How to set up subversion http access with serf

Tags: apache-http-server, svn

With Subversion 1.8 serf has become the default http access method for Subversion repositories. The [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) however still only contains information on how to use the old neon based access method.

Can somebody provide a working fully self-contained example of a serf-based configuration for apache?

Answer (score 0):

1. For server|clent *high-level* communication (and server-side configuaration, btw) **there are not** any difference in used library (neon or serf)
2. [Single location](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.perf.bulk-updates), in which neon|serf difference in action noted, contain also explanation of these differences and (possible, not mandatory) additional directive `SVNAllowBulkUpdates` and use-cases for it's usage